# Put ads on Orchard web site

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms, google-ads-api

I am very new to orchard and to web development itself. I would like to know is it possible to  integrate/add ads on Orchard web site and is there any resource about that.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with orchard, but here is a module that will integrate google analytics - http://orchardga.codeplex.com/. It's probably relatively easy to adjust this module to incorporate ads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you would have to build a module to do this yourself, as there aren't yet any modules in the Orchard Gallery that handle ads. There are some easy ways to do it without adding any code; it really depends on what you need to do to place your ads.

If you simply need to drop some html tags into certain pages you can accomplish this through the Orchard dashboard UI in at least a couple of different ways. The easiest would be through Widgets. Dashboard->widgets->Sidebar->Add->HtmlWidget. Drop in the HTML tags into the wysiwyg editor there and set up the rules so that this widget publishes to the desired Zone, and on the desired pages. Note, the instructions above said to publish to the "Sidebar" zone, but you could substitute that for any zone you want. You can use rules/layers to adjust which URL's your ads appear on.

If you need more complex behavior you might accomplish it by creating a custom content type that has a BodyPart, or you could code a custom widget. For example some systems like Doubleclick for Publishers want you to add a random string to the HTML of the ads for cache busting. I don't know that Orchard has any token replacements that could be used for that, but you could do it yourself by coding your own part that does a token replacement on the body part.

Comment: I want to add something like Google Ads. Or ads from such companies like http://buysellads.com/. Would that be possible ?

Comment: Ads are usually just a small bit of script. It's trivial to include either in your layout template or in a html widget. Making a module just for that seems immensely overkill, which is probably why there isn't a module for it.

Answer (score 0):

Add scripts directly to the view you want to show your ads on.